# Chrome captureVisibleTab in content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the captureVisibleTab chrome extension API in a content script so that in can capture every page while running in the background.

From what I can tell this has to be done using message passing. Can someone give me a quick example on how this could be achieved?

I was trying something like:

```
 {
 "name": "TabCapture",
 "version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Capture a tab",
"background" : {
"scripts" : ["background.js"],
"persistent": true
 },
 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_title": "Capture tab"      
 },
 "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*"],
  "js": ["jquery.js", "send.js"]
}
],
  "permissions" : ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

Send.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: "capture"}, function(response) {
 console.log(response.dataUrl);
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('holla');
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
        null,
        {},
        function(dataUrl)
        {
            sendResponse({imgSrc:dataUrl});
        }
    ); //remember that captureVisibleTab() is a statement
    return true;
}
```

);

But it does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, you just did a minor mistake. You are sending Object `{imgSrc: dataUrl}` where `imgSrc` is the property of the object but when you are accessing the object in content script you are accessing attribute `response.dataUrl`. Change it to `response.imgSrc`, reload extension then reload your pages and every thing will work fine. And there is a syntax error in `background.js` change the statement to :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('holla');
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
        null,
        {},
        function(dataUrl)
        {
            sendResponse({imgSrc:dataUrl});
        }
    ); //remember that captureVisibleTab() is a statement
    return true;
});
```

and add `"https://*/*"` in match url(in permissions) of content script also to capture all webpages.